# What is the best application available to create backup images of hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup, disk-image

We used to use a program called Acronis for creating image backups of an entire hard driver on a daily/weekly basis that could be used for restoring a crashed machine.I don't think Acronis works with Windows 7 now.  What is the best application out there for creating such backups? Does the backup system that is part of Windows 7 work well?

Comment: Could I make a friendly amendment to this question and ask for the best <i>free</i> application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the latest version does support windows 7:

http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/

> **support for Microsoft Windows 7**
>
> With Acronis True Image Home 2010, rest assured that all your important data including images, music, documents and applications are well protected

Comment: I'm using it with Windows 7 64bit. Works fine.

Comment: Acronis is better than Norton Ghost on Windows 7. I succed to make it work but it was pain in the neck tweeking it to.

Answer (score 1):

DriveXML should work for what you want:

http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) tool to create images of whole partitions.